# Average Ticks Passed on Combination Lock?

Tags: combinatorics

Trying to practice for a programming competition, but I am off by 20 for some reason that I can't figure out? (here is a [**link**](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2423) to the problem if you prefer that)

We have four variables:

N = Number of ticks on lock

T1, T2, T3 = The code numbers

1. If the mark initially points to tick T1, turn the dial exactly two full revolutions 
   clockwise and stop. Otherwise, turn the dial clockwise exactly two full revolutions clockwise and continue to turn it clockwise until the mark points to tick T1.
2. Turn the dial one full revolution counterclockwise and continue to turn it counterclockwise until the mark points to tick T2.
3. Turn the dial clockwise until the mark points to tick T3. The lock should now open.

The sample input {N = 80 : 20,40,50} has an average of 369.500 ticks. The answer I arrived at was 349.500?

To find the average for the first one I calculated the maximum and minimum number of ticks and divided that in half. I got 199.5.

For T2 you revolve once counterclockwise (80) and continue from T1 to T2 (60) for a total of 140.

For T3 continue from T2 to T3 (10).

I summed these averages to get 369.500. Could someone explain where I went wrong? I'm guessing I went wrong in step 1 but not sure? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: The problem should state whether the tick marks increase in clockwise our counter-clockwise sense, and whether they are on the dial (with the mark on the fixed outer rim) or on the outer rim (with the mark on the dial), Note that assuming the former answers to both questions, turning the dial clockwise makes the mark moves in _counter-clockwise_ sense, therefore in _decreasing_ order, relative to the tick marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's because you are couting the revolutions in the reverse direction (it's confusing, indeed). When you go counterclockwise it takes 20 to go from T1 to T2 (not 60) and then 70 (not 10) from T2 to T3. That gives $199.5+80+20+70=369.5$

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now. Thanks! :)